# prestashop 1.5 export retail final price

Tags: php, mysql, sql, export, prestashop-1.5

I have written a simple module to presta, which exports data of all products available in shop. Most of the data i get by simple sql queries, but i have problem with price. Now i have something like this:

```
$product = new Product($id,false);
$export_array[]['price'] = $product->price;
```

But price returned this way isnt the price that is shown in product page on presta (final retail price). I need some function that returns the same price that is in product page available for customer, and i want to avoid parsing this price from site for each product (it would be really slow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the function `getPriceStatic` available in the Product class.

You can find it and see how it works in `classes/Product.php` on line 2478